# Apply DNS configuration to all interfaces

Tags: linux-networking, ubuntu-20.04, netplan

On Ubuntu 20.04, how can I configure DNS for all Ethernet interfaces, regardless of how they've been named? I have some machines with `eth0` as the primary network interface and others with `ens5`. I'd like to use the same DNS configuration regardless of interface names. A colleague had recommended NetPlan, so that's what I've been trying first. The following configuration (with placeholder IP addresses, domain names, and MAC addresses) avoids some errors, such as an unescaped `*` being interpreted as a YAML alias attempt, or `match: {name: {}}` generating a `Name=` networkd configuration line that its logs flag as ignored. But it renders the machine unreachable.

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    all-ethernet-interfaces:
      match:
        name: "*"
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-dns: no
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.1.2.3, 10.1.2.4]
        search: [my.domain.com]
```

The only other netplan configuration fragment is 50-cloud-init.yaml:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp6: false
            match:
                macaddress: 01:20:34:50:67:08
            set-name: eth0
    version: 2
```

I have been able to work around the issue with duplicate, interface-specific, configuration sections, but I'd prefer to use a less repetitious and more flexible approach. I'm open to configuring systemd-networkd or systemd-resolved more directly instead of using netplan. I'll be using Ansible to apply the configuration once it's developed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need use the netplan to do it. So remove any dns-related settings from the netplan configuration files to avoid occasionally changes of dns settings. Then edit the `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` file according your configuration. See `man resolved.conf` for details. Anyway the systemd-resolved is main tool to manage dns by default.